# How to split object strings into individual strings? VueJS and computed property

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have an array of objects like so (200+ objects!):

```
[
    {
      Name: 'Aerial Farm',
      'Geometry Extracted': 'P, S'
    },
    {
      Name: 'Aircraft Hangar',
      'Geometry Extracted': 'P, C, S'
    }
]
```

I need to loop through the objects and split the values of the `Geometry Extracted` property into individual elements like "P" and "S" rather than a single string of "P, S".

I tried doing this as a computed property in VueJS:

```
computed: {
 geoList() {
   return this.items.map(i =>
     i['Geometry Extracted'].split(', ').join(', ')
   );
 }
}
```

and then Looping through it in my template like so:

```
    <ul>
        <li v-for='item in geoList' :key='item.id'>
          <a href='#'>{{item}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

but, the HTML was rendered like so:

```
...
<li>
    P, S
</li>
...
```

My goal is to get it like so:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">P</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">S</a>
</li>
```

My example [**code is here**](https://pastebin.com/ubdZ4HmV).

I hope this makes sense to what I am trying to say. Thanks!

Comment: why do you join the array after you split it? If i understand correctly you just need to replace
i['Geometry Extracted'].split(', ').join(', ')
with
i['Geometry Extracted'].split(', ').

Comment: `:key="item.id"` will always be undefined, btw. The elements of the array returned by `geoList` are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how you can create HTML elements containing those characters with Javascript. Edit the functions to suit your specific needs.

```js
var dummyObject = [{
    Name: 'Aerial Farm',
    'Geometry Extracted': 'P, S'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Aircraft Hangar',
    'Geometry Extracted': 'P, C, S'
  },
  {
    Name: ' Farm',
    'Geometry Extracted': 'P, S'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Aircraft ',
    'Geometry Extracted': 'X, X, X'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Aerial Google Farm',
    'Geometry Extracted': 'P, D'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Blue Hangar',
    'Geometry Extracted': 'P, C, S, N'
  },
]

function getGeometry(myObject) {
  return myObject['Geometry Extracted'].split(', ');
}

function createClasses(myArray) {
  myString = '';
  myArray.forEach(function(element) {
    myString += "<li><a href=\"#\">" + element + "</a></li>";
  })
  return myString;
}

function loopObjects(objectArray) {
  myString = '';
  objectArray.forEach(function(element) {
    myString += createClasses(getGeometry(element));
  })
  return myString;
}

console.log(loopObjects(dummyObject));
```

Comment: I don't think you understood his question. he needs to split the string

Comment: @relief.melone did you read the full code I posted? function getGeometry(myObject) {
  return myObject['Geometry Extracted'].split(', ');
}

Comment: woops. you're right ;) guess i missed that one. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Ok I thought I'd just comment but I guess I can make an answer as well. I think you're code is almost right. You're only error is that you join the array again after you split it. So

**('X,Y,Z').split(',') --> ['X','Y','Z']**

Basically you should stop here. But what you do then in your code is you join the array back to a string.

**['X','Y','Z'].join(',') --> 'X,Y,Z'**

Just leave the join and correct the line in your computed object from

```
i['Geometry Extracted'].split(', ').join(', ')
```

to

```
i['Geometry Extracted'].split(', ')
```

and you should be fine